# how can i install phidgets_ros package in groovy?

Tags: ros, phidgets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i need to read the data from a 3M Model 800 RFID reader. From this page:http://wiki.ros.org/phidgets_ros/Tutorials/Testing%20a%20Phidget%20RFID%20Reader
it is stated that i would need `RFIDscan.py` from `phidgets_ros` package. But i can't find a proper package with `RFIDscan.py` in it. Please help.

I have tried the following packages, but no help:

- http://foote-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/phidgets/
- http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arrg/ua_drivers/phidgets_py_api/
- http://www.phidgets.com/docs/OS_-_Linux#Quick_Downloads
- http://wiki.ros.org/phidgets_drivers

In http://wiki.ros.org/phidgets_ros, it is stated that i only need either `phidgets_py_api` and `foote-ros-pkg/phidgets/phidgetspp_c_api`, how can i get them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115786/how-can-i-install-phidgets_ros-package-in-groovy?/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2014-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-07**:
will this helps? http://code.google.com/p/ua-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/config/groovy-deb.rosinstall?spec=svn1657&r=1657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're trying to use the wrong driver. 3M is a different vendor than Phidgets, so there's probably no sense in trying to make the `phidgets_ros` driver work. Also, that would probably mean some work, since that package is ancient (no updates since 2010).

One thing I can tell you is that `phidgets_drivers` has nothing to do with `phidgets_ros`. It currently only provides drivers for the Phidgets IMU and IR sensors, not the RFID reader.

But, as I said, you're trying to use the wrong driver anyway.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-08**:
i have been worrying about that, just trying my luck, cause that is the only package related to RFID so far. and i had difficulties getting the device recognized. Just checking, if i manage to get the device by any chance, would i be able to read the tags without any driver (as in 3M is shown as ttyUSB)? cause i am using a serial232 to usb converter, which i think ros is able to recognise, and read the data via the converter?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-01-08**:
If you get ttyUSB running, it shouldn't be too hard to write your own ROS driver (i.e., a ROS node that reads from ttyUSB, converts that data into some ROS message format and publishes it). There are probably good examples of ROS nodes that already do that.

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-01-08**:
noted, thanks for your prompt reply. hopefully i can get it works. thanks alot :)